# Delegating thread-safety to ConcurrentMap and AtomicInteger

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to provide thread-safe implementation of the following container:

```
public interface ParameterMetaData<ValueType> {
    public String getName();
}

public interface Parameters {
    public <M> M getValue(ParameterMetaData<M> pmd);
    public <M> void put(ParameterMetaData<M> p, M value);
    public int size();
}
```

The thing is the size method should return the ***accurate*** number of paramters currently contained in a `Parameters` instance. So, my first attempt was to try delegating thread-safety as follows:

```
public final class ConcurrentParameters implements Parameters{

    private final ConcurrentMap<ParameterMetaData<?>, Object> parameters = 
                                                    new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    //Should represent the ACCURATE size of the internal map
    private final AtomicInteger size = new AtomicInteger();

    @Override
    public <M> M getValue(ParameterMetaData<M> pmd) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        M value = (M) parameters.get(pmd);
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public <M> void put(ParameterMetaData<M> p, M value){
        if(value == null)
            return;
        //The problem is in the code below
        M previous = (M) parameters.putIfAbsent(p, value);
        if(previous != null)
            //throw an exception indicating that the parameter already exists
        size.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size.intValue();
    }
```

The problem is that I can't just call `parameters.size()` on the `ConcurrentHashMap` instance to return the actual size, as that the operation performs traversal without locking and there's no guaratee that it will retrieve the actual size. It isn't acceptable in my case. So, I decided to maintain the field containing the size.

***QUESTION:*** Is it possible somehow to delegate thread safety and preserve the invariatns?

Comment: Without external locking, you cannot get higher precision than ConcurrentHashMap already provides, as you cannot guarantee atomically operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outcome you want to achieve is non-atomic. You want to modify map and then get count of elements that would be consistent in a scope of single thread. The only way to achieve that is to make this flow "atomic operation" by synchronizing access to the map. This is the only way to assure that count will not change due to modifications made in another thread.

Synchronize modify-count access to the map via `synchronized` or `Semaphore` to allow only single thread to modify map and count elements at the time.

Using additional field as a counter does not guarantee thread safety here, as after map modification and before counter manipulation, other thread can in fact modify map, and the counter value will not be valid.

This is the reason why map does not keeps its size internally but has to traversal over elements - to give most accurate results at given point in time.

**EDIT:**
To be 100% clear, this is the most convinient way to achieve this:

```
synchronized(yourMap){
    doSomethingWithTheMap();
    yourMap.size();
}
```

so if you will change every map operation to such block, you will guarantee that `size()` will return accurate count of elements. The only condition is that all data manipulations are done using such synchronized block.

Comment: BTW, notThreadSafe HashMap keeps track of the size internally by storing it in a field. So, in a way, the only way is to apply Monitor pattern and synchronize everything, right? Thus there is no need in CoincurrentMap and size-counter. HashMap would work out well.

Comment: That is why it is NTS :) If you will use `synchronized` block to access map and read count, then yes it will by TS and the count will be accurate. But if you only synchronize map manipulation methods and call `getSize()` outside of synchronized scope, this will still be NTS and not guaranteed to be consistent.

Comment: Ok, got it, thanks much. But is it reliable to count on that HashMap will not perform traversal when retrieving size? Or it would be safer to keep track of the size myself by stroing it into a field?

Comment: @St.Antario to speed things up (but probably you dont have to do this for small maps) you can keep track of elements yourself so it is always ready to read.

Comment: Accoriding to your update. Well but we can't provide mutual exclusion access to ConcurrentHashMap via external locking. Maybe I don't  understand your point....?

Comment: @Kayaman Because in case of external locking there is no point in `ConcurrentHashMap`. I might as well just synchronize access to 
`HashMap`. Actually I ended up writing just a monitor with `HashMap` internally.

Comment: @St.Antario That's what I meant. But you **can** do it.